# For loop in Dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a code as below. First the code should run based on the `dplyr::arrange(desc(sum.total))` then `dplyr::arrange(desc(sum.mpg))`  then as the outcome I would like to have a dataframe/datatable. Many thanks in advance

```
head(mtcars)

my.mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gear)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    sum.total = n(),
    sum.mpg = sum(mpg))%>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(sum.total)) # Run me first
  #dplyr::arrange(desc(sum.mpg))  # Second Dont run the line above but this
```

Expected Answer

```
#with dplyr::arrange(desc(sum.total))
gear sum.total sum.mpg

1     3        15    242.
2     4        12    294.
3     5         5    107.
#with dplyr::arrange(desc(sum.mpg))
gear sum.total sum.mpg

1     4        12    294.
2     3        15    242.
3     5         5    107.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my.mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gear)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    sum.total = n(),
    sum.mpg = sum(mpg)
lapply(c('sum.total', 'sum.mpg'), function(var) arrange(my.mtcars, desc(.data[[var]])))
```